# Python - Pandas: number/index of the minimum value in the given row

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have one pandas dataframe, with one row and multiple columns.

I want to get the column number/index of the minimum value in the given row.

The code I found was: df.columns.get_loc('colname')

The above code asks for a column name.
My dataframe doesn't have column names. I want to get the column location of the minimum value.

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Use `df['col'] = df.idxmin(axis=1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) with converting `DataFrame` to array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), only necessary only numeric data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[-5,3,6,9,2,-4]

})

print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1 -5
1  5  8  3  3
2  4  9  5  6
3  5  4  7  9
4  5  2  1  2
5  4  3  0 -4

df['col'] = df.values.argmin(axis=1)
print (df)
   B  C  D  E  col
0  4  7  1 -5    3
1  5  8  3  3    2
2  4  9  5  6    0
3  5  4  7  9    1
4  5  2  1  2    2
5  4  3  0 -4    3
```